# Get a reference to function from returned promise for this function.

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a code that I want to improve with a good style. I want to ask if something is possible and how to do it. 
I have e variable (this is not me actual code just example). In this variable 
a have returned promise from one function. I want to get reference for this function 
and call this function (if this is possible). I want to ask how to do it. 
This is me code:

```
var promise = (function () {
    return $.Deferred(function (def) {
        /**
          * Here will be done several
          * asinhronous things and
          * after this def.resolve();
          * will be called
         */

         /***
          * I want to get reference for
          * this function trought
          * returned promise
          * variable. (var promise).
         */
    }).promise();
})();
```

I would appreciate any opinions and help.

Best regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hеllo.

After much thinking, reading the documentation and looking at the examples I have concluded that it is impossible.